# Algorithm for separating Japanese characters one by one from an image using OpenCV

Tags: image, opencv, character

I have an application that needs separating Japanese characters one by one from an image.

Input: an image with ONE line of Japanese text. It can have halfwidth Katakana, halfwidth numbers, fullwidth Katakana, Hiragana and numbers as well. Maybe halfwidth or fullwidth English characters as well. (let's forget about English characters for the moment)

Issue:
I can easily separate out the characters by using adaptive thresholding, dilating and eroding. But there is one big issue.

Some of the Japanese characters have a space in between them. Like　川, 体, 休, 非. So simply looking at vertical white gaps doesn't help. Finding the width doesn't help either because there can be fullwidth characters (2btyte) or halfwidth characters (1byte). i seem to need an exquisite way to do this.

any idea how i should proceed with this? any idea is a good idea :)

here are couple of sample images. (characters circled in red are the problematic ones)

http://imageshack.us/a/img833/3810/e31z.png

http://imageshack.us/a/img12/2395/7mqn.png

Answer (score 1):

Don't expect to find one single simple algorithm able to do what you want, be prepared to combine a handful of techniques, including, but not limiting to those you already mentioned.

My personal advice, taken out of previous personal experience, would be for you to take a look at [template matching techniques](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html).

Basicaly that's what you'll need to do:

1. Select a few sample images of each symbol you want to identify to form your templates database.
2. Develop an algorithm to segment each individual character out of the image. That I think you've acomplished already.
3. Here it is important that you scale the characters and normalize their perspective so that they match the exact conditions on which the templates were generated. [getperspectivetransform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpperspective#getperspectivetransform) and [warpPerspective](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpperspective#void%20warpPerspective%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue%29) might come in handy.
4. Compare each character against each of your templates using [cv::matchTemplate](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#matchtemplate) for example.
5. Out of the top matches do some fine selection using heuristics like those you mentioned yourself, namely, checking for the existance of gaps on expected places and so on.
6. Test and retest, refining the heuristics for the closest cases till you reach the desired accuracy.

If you find yourself dealing with too much variety in terms of lighting conditions, characters colors, fonts, sizes and so on, you'll realize you'll be needing a huge database to cover all the various possibilities. In this case, it might help to use some transform invariant to the varying conditions. For character identification I believe skeletonization could work well. Take a look at [topological skeleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton) and [morphological skeleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_skeleton) and also [here](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-morphological-skeleton/) for a brief example.

Comment: Those images I have uploaded are NOT the real inputs. The real inputs are much worse than that. They are coming from a mobile phone camera. So they will be much worse that those images I posted. 

Yes, I knew just one algorithm was not going to cut it. I will look into template matching. I'm quite new to OpenCV as well, so I need to do a lot of reading. Many thanks to pointing me in a direction to pursue.

Comment: @Anusha considering you might be dealing with widely varying conditions, I updated my answer to include a couple of tips more.

Answer (score 0):

Hope [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) is what you need to do. As this [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/15711/ocr-support-in-opencv/) says opencv doesnt support OCR. But there is another opensource [tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) which will do this. Just check if this helps.

Few more links I got on googling.

[Opencv OCR](http://ayoungprogrammer.blogspot.in/2013/01/equation-ocr-part-1-using-contours-to.html)

[OCR exaple in Opencv](http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/)

Hope this helps!